# Does lacquer coat protect a PCB from ESD damage?

Tags: esd

Does lacquer coat protect PCB from ESD?

It seems that it actually does, because lacquer is isolation and it's a barrier from my body to the circuit. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Add some ESD protection circuitry. It's not too difficult.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes and no.

Yes:  It is possible to cover a PCB with something like lacquer and this would offer some protection.

No:  The protection that lacquer offers is not enough.  Not even close, actually.

The lacquer would protect the PCB from a direct zap to its circuits.  The issue is that direct zaps are not usually the problem.  The problems that ESD causes are usually from zaps to the cables and connectors (which cannot be covered in lacquer), or due to induced spikes on the wires from nearby ESD zaps.

In the latter case, lets say that you touch a door frame and it causes a zap.  That zap will radiate lots of RF energy which can get picked up by cables and traces on the PCB.  Those cables and traces act as an antenna, receiving the RF energy that the zap creates.  If the zap is strong enough, or close enough, it can cause things to not behave correctly.  I have seen badly designed PCB's die from a static zap 8+ feet away.   Lacquer won't protect from that.

Comment: Suppose, my PCB is closed from the World. No connector and cables. But human can touch the PCB. Is it enough to lacquer the PCB for protection from ESD?

Comment: @user14284  No, it is not enough.  An ESD spark in the same room can still couple into traces on the PCB.  This doesn't even require being able to touch the PCB.  Touching the PCB makes things even more difficult.  The best thing is to do basic good engineering with ESD protection and not rely on lacquer (which has other issues, like guaranteeing if it is  properly covering everything well).

Answer (score 6):

When I learned about ESD conformity testing, the most surprising thing for me was the part where you put a metal plate upright next to your equipment under test.

You discharge some high voltage load onto the metal plate, and you look how the device under test, some decimeters away from the metal plate, reacts. Note that there is no, really no, direct discharge from the ESD gun onto your gadget-under-test. This means that a coating will not help at all during this part of the test.

It's the field alone that may cause some unexpected behavior, like resets being triggered or memory cells being altered, causing your code to do weird things.

Note: Industrial electronics and the fried-up configurations you will encounter are fun. Reality is always worse than any EMC standard.

Answer (score 1):

Put in simple terms: Not in any way you could rely on.

Coating something with an insulator will of course have **some** effect, but not in any way you could rely on to give ANY useful ESD/EMC protection. That **must** come from the design of your circuit / device.